# Difficulty understanding difference between == and ===

Tags: core-language, expression-test

After doing this:

```
Clear[f, h]
f[z_] = .66 I Cos[z];
h[c_] := {Re[c], Im[c], Nest[f, c, 200]};
complexpts = 
  Flatten[Table[a + b I, {a, 0., 8, 8/249}, {b, -4., 4, 8/249}], 1];
t1 = Map[h, complexpts] // Chop
```

This works:

```
Select[t1, Not[#[[3]] === Indeterminate] &]
```

But why doesn't this work:

```
Select[t1, Not[#[[3]] == Indeterminate] &]
```

And why doesn't this work:

```
Select[t1, (#[[3]] != Indeterminate) &]
```

Comment: Equal (==) tests for numerical equality, SameQ(===) and its negation UnsameQ(=!=) test for symbolic equality.  Since Indeterminate is not a number, == and != fail.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Nice explanations.

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153694)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`===` (`SameQ`) is structural equality. `a === b` is `True` if `a` and `b` are exactly the same data structure (expressions), and `False` otherwise.  For `===` it doesn't matter what `a` and `b` *represent*.  Also, like nearly all Mathematica functions ending in `Q`, `===` *always* evaluates to either `True` or `False` (but nothing else).

`==` is mathematical equality. `a == b` represents the equality of two mathematical expressions.  It may or may not evaluate to `True` or `False`.  Equations are represented in terms of `==`

`Indeterminate == someNumber` never evaluates in Mathematica.  You end up with something that is neither `False` nor `True` in `Select`.  `Select` treats that as if it were false.  Compare `Select[{1,2,3}, foo]` where `foo` is an arbitrary symbol (not `True` or `False`).  Also consider that `Not[foo]` doesn't evaluate (because `foo` is here treated as a yet-unknown logical variable).

Comment: Why would `12 == "a"` evaluate ?

Comment: @eldo - because a string (non-number) can never equal a number, Whereas, a symbolic expression may or may not equal a number.

Comment: "`a == b` represents the equality of two mathematical expressions. It may or may not evaluate to `True` or `False`." Maybe it's worth noting that Mma may fail to perform the numerically "obvious" comparison and return an unevaluated, non-Boolean result in surprising situations. For instance, `Sqrt[(2 - Sqrt[3])^2 + (-3 + 2 Sqrt[3])^2] == 4 - 2 Sqrt[3]` doesn't evaluate straight to `True`, but does so when "pushed" with `Simplify`.