# Difference between != and =!=

Tags: syntax, expression-test

I (think I) understand the difference between == (semantic) and === (syntactic). So when comparing != and =!= I was expecting a similar difference. So can anyone explain why the third line in this code gives a different result than the other three lines?

```
Sin[g[u]] /. f_[x__] /; f == Sin -> {f, x}
Sin[g[u]] /. f_[x__] /; f === Sin -> {f, x}
Sin[g[u]] /. f_[x__] /; f != Tan -> {f, x}
Sin[g[u]] /. f_[x__] /; f =!= Tan -> {f, x}
```

Comment: So you're question really is just why doesn't `Sin != Tan` evaluate to `True`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 If that is what is going on, then that is my question

Comment: Yes, the pattern replacement does not happen because `Sin != Tan` does not evaluate to `True`. That's an answer to one question, I suppose. Another question is why doesn't `Sin != Tan` evaluate. I suppose symbols do not have a fixed value: try `Block[{Sin = Tan}, Sin != Tan]`.  (The exact circumstances for `==` and `!=` to evaluate are a little vague to me.)

Comment: Strange (minor) exceptions: Note that if `x` has no value, `x != x` returns `False` even though it is not guaranteed to be false: It's not `False` if `x` is set to `Indeterminate`, `Undefined`, or a value that changes every time `x` is evaluated -- maybe there are other cases.  Similarly for `==`. The case `x != x` is covered in the docs (`False` if the two sides are "identical"), but it seems inconsistent with "`Unequal` returns `True` if elements are guaranteed unequal...."

Comment: @Michael, I suppose this is a bit similar to IEEE's convention that NaN is not equal to itself.

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98889)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `Sin!=Tan` rule is unevaluated, since there is not enough data to decide whether `Sin` and `Tan` may yield the same information.  If they're not given arguments they're simply symbols.  And `!=` doesn't check for exact symbol equivalence, from the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unequal.html)
 "Unequal returns True if elements are guaranteed unequal, and otherwise stays unevaluated."

Evaluate:  `Sin!=Tan` on its own and you get back unevaluated `Sin!=Tan`. There's  not enough information for Mathematica to decide if the Symbols may yield something that is equivalent, so it stays unevaluated and thus doesn't trigger the conditional on the rule.

You may be confused because you know `Sin[x]` and `Tan[x]` mean different things.  (Though recognize `Sin[0]==Tan[0]`).

Note: `Sin=!=Tan` absolutely evaluates to `True` as they are not the *exact same* symbol.  `UnsameQ` returns `True` unless the expressions on the lhs and rhs are strictly identical. ([documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnsameQ.html))

Answer (score 13):

Mathematica is a symbolic language. In practice, this often means that you can write expressions that cannot be immediately computed without triggering any errors.

In other languages `x+1` makes no sense if `x` has no numerical value.  In Mathematica `x+1` simply stays unevaluated until `x` gets a value.

This applies to `==` as well. In `a!=b`, `a` and `b` are considered mathematical variables. It can't be decided whether `a!=b` is `True` or `False` until you give explicit values to `a` and `b`.

All this means that you must be careful when using constructs that expect a `True` or `False` value. You could accidentally be passing in a value that is neither `True` nor `False` and still not trigger an error, the same way as `x+1` does not trigger an error despite `x` not having a value.  Different constructs behave differently in this situation, but the two typical approaches are:

- Treat anything that isn't `True` as `False`. This is the case with [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) and explains your results.  `Sin != Tan` is not `True`. It just stays unevaluated, therefore it is treated as `False` by `Condition`.
- Simply do not evaluate.  This is the case e.g. with `If`:

  ```
   If[x == y, 1, 2]
   (* If[x == y, 1, 2] *)
  ```

  [`If`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html) in fact has a fourth argument which lets you explicitly handle values that are neither true nor false.

Other approaches to deal with this consequence of the symbolic nature of the language is to have functions which *always* evaluate to `True` or `False`, no matter what their argument.  Functions with names ending in `Q` are almost always like this.  `===` is called `SameQ`, and it always evaluates. `DirectedGraphQ` also always evaluates: if you pass in a non-graph value, it returns `False` (you can think of it like this: something that is not a graph cannot be a directed graph). A very common mistake is to assume that some functions stay unevaluated in the same way as `x+1` when in fact they don't, e.g. `EvenQ[x]` or `OddQ[x]` immediately evaluate to `False` if `x` has no value.

There is also a function, [`TrueQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrueQ.html), that serves to explicitly convert anything not `True` to `False`.

Comment: If `==` and `!=` always evaluated, we'd never be able to use them in `Solve[]`, `Reduce[]`, etc.

Comment: "If in fact has a third argument..." I think you mean 4th argument, but good point nonetheless.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Thanks! I didn't count the first one :-)

Comment: Not giving an explicit value is not a problem with Sin==Sin, this evaluates to True...

Comment: @ImreVégh I don't understand your point. Is it not clear that this is `True` *regardless* of the symbol's value?